# dropzone doesnt upload some pictures (internal server error 500)

Tags: javascript, php, server, dropzone.js

i use dropzone for file(images) upload. when i upload on my local computer, files upload successfully. but when i upload files on my web host, dropzone gives iternal server error on some pictures(not for all). just for experiment, i uploaded one picture several times. and sometimes dropzone gives an error, and sometime doesnt(on the same picture). not to blame picture's size (i also tried pictures about 4-5 kb). here's my code

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropZone",  { url: "{{action('AdminToursController@storeImage')}}",
    addRemoveLinks : true
} );
myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
    formData.append("_token", $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')); // Laravel expect the token post value to be named _token by default

});
var i = 1;
myDropzone.on('complete', function(a, b, c){
    var src = JSON.parse(a.xhr.responseText).uploaded_path;
    $("<input type='hidden' name='gallery-img-" + i++ + "' value='"+ src + "'/>").appendTo('.tour-add-form');
    addRemoveLinks : true;
});
```

Comment: error 500 is a server error, client code isn't going to help much in solving your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of permissions. solved by setting permissions to 775 uploads directory